# How to solve $\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\left|x + 1\right|e^{-x}}{x} $?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to solve this limit
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\left|x + 1\right|e^{-x}}{x} $$
but I get stuck with
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} -\frac{xe^{-x} + e^{-x}}{x} $$

I've tried to transform it in several ways but I get indeterminate forms every time.

Comment: Are you allowed to use L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: Of course :) I don't understand why I got the question edited. Looking at other questions, nobody uses the `\large` command to formatting the text.

Comment: I rolled back the edit with the hopes that whoever earned +2 rep for adding nothing via edit (just \large which wasn't helpful) will lose those two points.

Comment: Thanks. The normal size of articles text written in latex that I usually read is 10 or 11pt and the punctuation in math environment is a personal choiche.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the limit into a product:

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{|x+1|e^{-x}}{x}=\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{|x+1|}{x}\cdot e^{-x}.$$

Using your observation that $|x+1|=-(x+1)$ when $x\to-\infty$ tells you that $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{|x+1|}{x}=-1.$$  Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to-\infty}e^{-x}=\infty$ you can split of the limit of a product into the product of limits and have:

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{|x+1|}{x}e^{-x}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{|x+1|}{x}\lim_{x\to-\infty}e^{-x}=(-1)(\infty)=-\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

Transform $-x \mapsto x'$, so our limit becomes

$$\lim \limits_{x' \to \infty} -\dfrac{|1 - x'|e^{x'}}{x'}$$
$$\lim \limits_{x' \to \infty} - \left|\dfrac{1 - x'}{x'}\right| e^{x'}$$

The first factor clearly goes to $1$ while the second goes to infinity, so the limit in total is $-\infty$.